# How do I get fmt-like functionality for Vim in Windows?

Tags: windows, vim

I've found fmt to be extremely useful with Vim for formatting code comments. Unfortunately, I'm now working on Windows and fmt is not available. Is there a way to get similar functionality in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/). You can install just the [CoreUtils package](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) to get `fmt`. Make sure you edit your environment's PATH variable to point to GnuWin32's bin directory.

Comment: I tried this but aren't getting the same result as on mac, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013090/text-de-justification-to-get-correct-substring, any ideas?