# Using vim, is there a command to have pasted text automatically line-wrapped?

Tags: ruby, vim, text, edit

**CONTEXT**: Part of a job I'm doing involves pasting paragraphs of text from a word doc into a ruby file.

**PROBLEM**: These paragraphs are getting pasted in as a single very long line of text and I have to manually insert newlines to make the lines of reasonable length.

**SOLUTION**: Is there a way to make the pasting function "aware" of reasonable margin limits and wrap the text when I paste it in?

Comment: Do you want to wrap the text, as in keep it one long line but make it viewable, or break the text up at some arbitrary boundary, say 70 characters?

Comment: @Al G I want an arbitrary boundary, of reasonable size, around 70 characters sounds reasonable

Answer (score 15, accepted):

first do a set textwidth

```
:set tw=80
```

then do `gqq`   - for a single line

for the whole file

```
ggVGgqq
```

Comment: `gggqG` is a bit move *vimmish*. Trying to avoid the visual mode is a good exercise :D

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can do this with:

`:set wrap`

This will show the text as wrapped without altering the underlying structure or inserting line breaks.  It's sometimes also helpful to:

`:set linebreak`

This causes vim to wrap without breaking words.

It's also possible to:

`:set wrapmargin`

Which sets how far on the right wrapping should start.

Comment: `:set wrap` doesn't really do it though if the text pasted already has internal line breaks. They won't be reformatted, and you'll end up with some short lines.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski The OP states that the text appears as a "single very long line of text" which suggests that internal line breaks won't be a problem.

Comment: @Benj Don't these just cause the text to wrap "visually" but not structurally. My apologies if the post wasn't clear but I want that single line of text to actually be broken up into several, separate individual lines of text, like how the paragraph looks in the word document.

Comment: @steve_gallagher Yes, this is true, Vim can handle both possibilities.  Actually `:set wrap` is closer to what Word does since word doesn't insert line breaks when wrapping either.

Answer (score 4):

vi, vim, and gvim support the 'ex' level commands:

```
:set ws wm=10
```

which sets a wrap margin at 10 characters from the right border and enforces a "wrap scan" - automatic wrapping as you type.  This won't work for pasting text, though.  For that, the 'fmt' command exists, which is native to Unix/Linux and supplied on Cygwin and GnuWin32 (see [How do I get fmt-like functionality for Vim in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737641/how-do-i-get-fmt-like-functionality-for-vim-in-windows))..

The "fmt" command provides a filter for reformatting existing text with word breaks, and it accepts a numeric flag (e.g., "-80") to specify line width.  You can invoke this from within the vim editor, after pasting in the long lines.

You do:

```
!!fmt
```

to reformat a long line (keyboard shortcut for ex command ":.!fmt")

Or, to rewrap a whole paragraph:

```
!}fmt
```

from the paragraph's first line.

This should save you some time.

Answer (score 3):

I typically have a need to import text and then have to wrap the whole document:
I use:

`:g/./normal gqq`

Hope that helps.